How do i allocate the unallocated space of head of the drive?
Recently I bought an SSD and used the Hasleo disk clone tool to copy my OS from an HDD and migrate it to the new SSE. After I booted my PC I decided to delete the Windows installation in the HDD, but now I can't allocate that freed-up space.
Can someone tell me a way to make use of this unallocated space?


have you right clicked the unallocated block?

yeah i tried extending it, allocating it but it always results in this error "There is not enough space on the disc to perform this operation"  I have 60~ GB free on the D: Partition

As it is now the only operation you can do is to create a new partition in the unallocated space.

I have 60~ GB free on the D: Partition what does that have to do with the unallocated space? The only option I get in unallocated space is to "New Simple Volume" - what option are you choosing?

It is easy to extend an existing partition to unallocated space farther along a drive. It is a real nuisance to move partitions down to that unallocated space. The easiest thing to do is right-click that space, make a new simple volume, and format as you wish.

i get this error ''There is not enough space on the disc to perform this operation'' while trying the "New Simple Volume" option. But i literally have 60 GB free on the next volume of the same drive

Do you get that error when right-clicking the unallocated space? Again... Whatever free space you have or don't have in any other partition in the same drive is IRRELEVANT. Your insistence suggests you don't really know what you're doing...

You cannot just assign this space to another partition elsewhere on the drive. partitions must exit in contiguous space, even on SSDs. So the only thing you can do with this unallocated space would be to create a simple volume with it, as others have noted. Rearranging partitions on a drive to make this free space available to add to one of the existing partitions can be done, but there's a much higher chance of data loss, and it is likely far easier to backup the drive data, perform a complete fresh OS install, and repartition the entire drive as desired.

Windows doesn't let me allocate this unallocated space and i can't be bothered to wipe and backup this drive as i use it as my backup drive, is there any way to make this space usable without wiping the whole drive?
